# VS 2013 setup project update package fails for running executable

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, sccm

I have created a setup project (using VS 2013) to update my existing application on desktop clients. Previously, application has already been installed with same project output package. So,

- I have changed the setup project version
- Product code is updated in the meantime
- RemovePreviouVersions is checked

MSI will be delivered via Microsoft SCCM 2012 R2 and has to support silent installation.

My problem is, application has been running through all clients and setup can't replace existing executable file with an error.

Any advice would be appreciated.

More Info:

Installer also prompts a dialog during interactive mode:

> The following applications are using files which the installer must update.You can either close the application and click "Try Again", click "Continue" so that the installer continues the installation, and replaces these files when your system restarts.

Same behaviour is observed when installer is launched by "Run as administrator" option.

Thanks,

Comment: There's not enough info here. Does "setup can't replace existing executable file with an error." mean that the install fails silently? Does it upgrade correctly in UI mode? Does it require admin privilege to install, because a silent install won't offer an elevation dialog and it will fail. Ask them to use an msiexec command line with /l*vx [path to a text log file] to see what the verbose log says about the failure.

Comment: I have provided more info. Thankx

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. That dialog is a standard FilesInUse dialog prompting the user to shut down programs to avoid a reboot at the end of the install. At the risk of stating the obvious, executables that are in use cannot be replaced until the process finishes, and most users would rather shut down a program than be required to reboot. This FilesInUse dialog will be shown anytime that installer UI is enabled. If you do a fully silent install then that dialog will not be shown (because silent really means silent), and if there are in fact files that needs replacing the install will reboot at the end automatically in a fully silent install.

Other tools that generate MSIs have support for closing down running apps, but then again no user wants to suddenly find that they have lost data because an install forcibly shut down an app they were running.

Apps can integrate with the Restart Manager if they want to be informed of install-related reboots and Windows will restart them after the reboot.

[Restart Manager Support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/772868/Restart-Manager-Support-For-Windows-Application)

[How do I add support for Restart Manager](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-vista-restart-manager.html)